# Convert generic to interface in constructor

Tags: c#, generics

I'm stuck on what I would think would be something easily doable, but I can't seem to make it work. The issue is as follows:

1. I have a class ("Response") containing an interface property  ("IPayload") that also accepts that interface property in a constructor.
2. I have another class containing a method that performs work and creates an instance of Response. It accepts a type parameter constrained to IPayload and creates an instance of List (again, where T is constrained to IPayload) that it attempts to add to response.
3. When I try to implement the constructor, I cannot seem to cast the generic object from the helper method into an acceptable IPayload instance for use with the constructor. I would think that I could just use something like (T) or something like (typeof(T)) but I get compile errors all around. I would think this should be doable buy maybe not? Thoughts appreciated. Simplified code below.

   ```
   public interface IPayload
   {
       // deliberately generic
   }

   public class Response
   {
       public Response(IEnumerable<IPayload> payload) => Payload = payload;
       public IEnumerable<IPayload> Payload { get; set; }
   }
   public class Worker
   {

       public Response DoWork<T>() where T : IPayload, new()
       {
           List<T> payload = new List<T>();

           // do stuff to construct payload
           // This throws a compile error: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Interfaces.IPayload>'
           Response response = new Response(payload);

           return response;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: well then try converting the list `Response response = new Response(payload.OfType<IPayload>());`. looks like a Covariance, Contravariance issue. If the variable was declared `var payload = new List<IPayload>();` it would have worked no problem.

Comment: Reference [Variance in Generic Interfaces (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces)

Comment: Cannot thank you enough @Nkosi. This worked like a charm. Much love.

Comment: I've got this working, but now a followup question: when trying to serialize this to JSON I'm not able to include the instantiated type. The best it gives me is the interface: "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Response.Interfaces.IPayload, ClassLibrary1]], mscorlib",

Answer (score 1):

If the consumer of the response doesn't care about the concrete type, I suggest you use `List<IPayload>` instead of `List<T>`. This resolves the compilation error. You can, of course, add any object to the list as long as it implements IPayload, so you can still add `new T()` if you want.

```
public Response DoWork<T>() where T : IPayload, new()
{
    IEnumerable<IPayload> payload = new List<IPayload>() { new T () };
    Response response = new Response(payload);
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `class` to `where` clause.

```
public Response DoWork<T>() where T : class, IPayload, new()
```